How to replace an entry in KeyStore?
This is my code:
val oldAlias = "oldAlias"
val newAlias = "newAlias"

if (keyStore.containsAlias(oldAlias) && keyStore.containsAlias(newAlias)) {
    try {
        deleteKeyStore(oldAlias)
        val newEntry: KeyStore.Entry = keyStore.getEntry(newAlias, null)
        keyStore.setEntry(oldAlias, newEntry, protParam = null) // exception is thrown here
        deleteKeyStore(newAlias)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }
}

I've tried running the method with and without deleting the oldAlias before calling the setEntry() method, but it doesn't help.
In both cases, if I don't delete the old alias or don't delete it, the method throws this exception:

KeyStoreException: Can only replace keys with the same alias: oldName != newName in the same target domain: 0 != 0

How can I replace the value by key in KeyStore?
